# Averaging numbers on the blackboard

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, reachability, blackboard

Aatif sees the numbers $ 1 , 2 , 3 , .... , 2016 $ written on the blackboard. In a move Aatif can pick any two numbers on the blackboard, erase them and write instead once their average. As an example, the numbers $1$ and $8$ may be replaced by $4 \frac{1}{2}$, and the numbers $2$ and $10$ may be replaced by $6$.

After $2015$ moves the blackboard only contains a single number. Can Aatif make his moves so that the final number is $2$?

Comment: Incidentally, the maximum final number for values 1 .. n is $n-1 + 1/(2^n)$

Comment: @KyleHale:  and the minimum final number, if I'm not mistaken, is $2 - (n+2)/2^n$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I came up with $2 - 1/2^(n-1)$. For example, if n = 3, the minimum you can do is $7/4$.

Comment: @KyleHale: Hmm, you're right — I forgot a term when I was summing things up.

Comment: @KyleHale , how did you calculate the maximum and the minimum values ? Can you please show the exact method ?

Comment: @HemantAgarwal Kind of hard to explain in a comment. Intuitively it's a recursive, Fibonacci-like sequence. So MAX(N) = (MAX(N-1) + N) / 2. To maximize value / minimize loss, always average the two smallest remaining numbers. Now imagine you discard the fraction every time. then n and n-1 would always leave behind n-1, even for the very last averaging. So then just including the fraction in its own piecewise function, you get 1/2 in the first averaging and then 0 thereafter, dividing it by 2 for each step from 1 to n, so $n-1 + 1/2^n$

Comment: And for minimum, same concept but in reverse: to maximize loss, always average the two largest remaining numbers. And since we're going backwards, it's more intuitive to instead round up the fraction every time, and include the difference as a piecewise faction. So n and n-1 leaves behind n, and you get -1/2 for the first averaging and then 0 thereafter. So since the final averaging is 1 and 2, you get $2 - 1/2^(n-1)$.

Comment: There's an old riddle: a woman dies owning 17 cats. In her will, she stipulates 1/3 of her cats go to her son, 1/2 go to her daughter, and 1/9 go to her niece. The answer is: her lawyer adds his own cat to the collection, making 18, giving 6 to the son, 9 the daughter, and 2 to the niece - leaving his own cat which he retrieved.

It's best to think of the fractional part of the sums as a cat you can put in or take out as you please, as it makes no impact on the rest of the averaging.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Yes

First choose $2014$ and $2016$. Average = $2015$. Now take the $2015$s. Their average is $2015$.

Now choose $2015$ and $2013$. Average = $2014$.

Choose $2014$ and $2012$. Average = $2013$.

Note that we can keep on continuing this approach and end up with a situation like $1$, $2$ and $4$ in the end.

From here, choose $2$ and $4$. Average = $3$. Average of $1$ and $3$ is $2$.

Comment: [Manal Mohania](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17659/manal-mohania)'s solution works great. This is my attempt in JavaScript: [(Plnkr)](https://plnkr.co/edit/4ao9I9RNVHqg8XvNkkSG?p=preview)

Answer (score 12):

> Yes

Reasoning:

> We can get 2 with 1 and 3. Very well then let us save 1 for last. We can get 3 with 2 and 4. Let us save 2 for that. We can get... and so on all the way up until we have saved all the numbers from 1 to 2014.

After this we...

> ...cannot go any higher because we cannot average 2015 and 2017; there is no 2017. However, averaging first 2014 and 2016 gives us 2015. 2015 and 2015 gives us 2015. So now we can start moving back again: 2013 and 2015 gives us 2014. 2012 and 2014 gives us 2013.

...going all the way back to...

> 1 and 3, which gives us 2.