# Aatif averages numbers on the blackboard

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, reachability, blackboard

Aatif has averaged numbers and made the final number $2$: 
[Averaging numbers on the blackboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30815/averaging-numbers-on-the-blackboard)

Today Aatif once again sees the numbers $ 1 , 2 , 3 , .... , 2016 $ written on the blackboard. In one move Aatif may pick any two numbers on the blackboard, erase them and write instead once their average. As an example, the numbers $1$ and $8$ may be replaced by $4 \frac{1}{2}$, and the numbers $2$ and $10$ may be replaced by $6$.

After $2015$ moves the blackboard only contains a single number. Can Aatif make his moves so that the final number is $999$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is :

> YES

Explanation :

> You can use [the same technique as before](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/30817/20274) to reduce number bigger than $999$ to $1001$ and numbers smaller than $999$ to $997$.
>
>  Big numbers :
>  First choose $2014$ and $2016$. Average = $2015$. Now take the $2015$s. Their average is $2015$ 
>  Now choose $2015$ and $2013$. Average = $2014$
>  Choose $2012$ and $2014$. Average = $2013$ ...
>  You can go on until you average $1000$ and $1002$ to $1001$
>
>  You go the same way for small numbers :
>  Choose $1$ and $3$. Average : $2$. Now take the $2$s. Their average is still $2$.
>  Choose $4$ and $2$. Average : $3$.
>  Choose $5$ and $3$, average : $4$.
>  You can go on until you average $998$ and $996$ in $997$.
>
>  Now you have $997$, $999$ and $1001$ on the blackboard :
>  Average $1001$ and $997$ in $999$.
>  Average $999$ and $999$ in $999$.

Generalization :

> You can use the exact same technique for integers between $4$ and $2013$. Extremities are a little different but you can easily adapt this to find $2$, $3$, $2014$ or $2015$.
>  **The final number on the blackboard can be any integer between $2$ an $2015$.**